# how auto run pppoe connection for valid ip on windows server 2008 [startup folder not help]

Tags: windows-server-2008, startup, pppoe

i bought an ip valid from my adsl isp and made a pppoe connection for using that ip in my windows server 2008.(my server)
i want to force that connection to run automatically when log off/on or windows starts!
i made a shortcut of that connection in start up folder of start menu-programs / but does not work when windows starts (`before login`)!
also i test scheduled task , but it seems in scheduled task we should define time(`but we need windows startup option`)!!!

how can i do this job in windows server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging something outside of your local subnet (for instance on the internet) and configuring the PPPOE conection to be demand dial should accomplish what you are asking. But having said that, I am not sure I understand your question.  Just to clarify, you purchased a static IP and want to use that with your PPPOE connection?  Typically a static IP would be on your router or firewall, not used directly on your server.